# Finding the object for which the constructor will be called while converting one class type to another class type

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operators

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class meter
{
    private:
      float m;
    public:
       meter()
       {
           m=0.0;
       }
       meter(float m1)
       {
           m=m1;
       }
       void display()
       {
           cout<<"the equivalient meter is "<<m<<endl;
       }
};
class feet
{
    private:
      float f;
    public:
        void input()
        {
            cout<<"enter the value of feet"<<endl;
            cin>>f;
        }
        operator meter()
        {
            float m1=f*0.3048;
            return(meter(m1)); //line of interest
        }
};
int main()
{
    feet f2;
    meter m2;
    f2.input();
    m2=f2; //type conversion call
    m2.display();
    return(0);
}
```

in the above mentioned code, in the line of interest; "return(meter(m1))" calls the constructor meter(float m1) for which object? I tried debugging and observing one step at a time, still could not figure out, I observed no new object being created. Is it  for the object m2?

Comment: its a constructor, it is constructing a meter object. It is not called on something previously, a constructor never is. It doesn't have a name because it is constructing a temporary.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking.  `return(meter(m1));` constructs an unnamed object of type `meter` using the constructor that accepts a `float`.   The way in which such an object is assigned to `m2` (or, more generally, returned to the caller) varies between C++ standards.

Answer (score 1):

It's calling constructor of class `meter`.
It creates temporary object.
It is unnamed object. [More Informations here](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bluegene/IBMdocs/compiler/xlc-8.0/html/language/ref/cplr382.htm).

Your code will work like this.

1. `m2 = f2.meter()`
2. `f2.meter()` returns temp object.
3. `m2.operator=(<temp object>)`

`meter m = meter(1.2);`
This code is also using temporary object.

Check this [code](https://ideone.com/Zu3WiS) to check lifetime of temporary object.